# Angular 2 Dependency Injection: Can't resolve all parameters (no dep chain, no barrel)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-services, angular2-di

I've been trying to follow one example in the ng-book 2 and ran into difficulties in the DI chapter.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <button (click)="invokeService()">Get Value</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public myService: MyService) {}

    invokeService() {
        console.log(this.myService.getValue());
    }
}
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    getValue(): string {
        return 'a value';
    }
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here's a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/KSXE9tnRj4tffiISyp0i it totally works when creating the ReflectiveInjector manually, but when i try to take the easy way and declare it in providers on the NgModule it fails giving me "Can't resolve all dependencies for AppComponent". I checked the other answers and as you see there are no circular deps or barrel-related problems - it's all in one file. Any hints would appreciated!

Comment: If MyService is in the same module, I think it should be declared in the declarations as well, if it is in a seperate module, it should be in the imports array, have you tried that?

Comment: Tried adding MyService to the NgModule declarations array in the plunker and it produced the following Error: (SystemJS) Error: Unexpected value 'MyService' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Sorry scrap that, it's only applicable for components.  However, try adding providers: [MyService] in the AppComponent metadata under the selector / template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting multiple classes in one file (I'm sure this is for testing only), the order of the files must be in check. Say your `AppComponent` is referencing your `MyService`, so the definition of `MyService` must be put on top of `AppComponent`. Hence, your code must look something like this:

```
import { Component, ReflectiveInjector, Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor() {}

    getValue(): string {
        return 'a value';
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <button (click)="invokeService()">Get Value</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    // private myService: MyService;

    constructor(public myService: MyService) {
        // let injector: any = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([MyService]);
        // this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
        // console.log('Same instance? ', this.myService === injector.get(MyService));
    }

    invokeService() {
        console.log(this.myService.getValue());
    }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: WOW that did the trick! The tutorials never mention such a thing that the order in which classes are declared matters. Plus the error message is somewhat misleading - making you look into if you declared or provided the dependency right etc... anyway, thanks for the help!